# How can I prevent my libGDX live wallpaper from causing black font color on the Android home screen?

Tags: android, libgdx, live-wallpaper, android-wallpaper, wallpapermanager

I've encountered a perplexing issue. When users set my wallpaper, the font color of the app names on their home screens turns black, making it difficult to read due to the wallpaper's dark colors.

I thoroughly reviewed my libGDX code to check for any explicit settings related to font colors, but couldn't find any that would affect the home screen's font color.
Since I hadn't defined any specific font color in my code, I expected the font color on the Android home screen to remain unchanged, adapting to the dark colors used in the wallpaper, thus remaining readable.
Contrary to my expectations, when I set my live wallpaper, the font color of the app names on the home screen turned black, causing readability issues due to the wallpaper's dark colors. This behavior was unique to my wallpaper app, and I couldn't determine the reason behind it

Comment: Is this android 12 picking a font colour based on your dark wallpaper? https://support.google.com/pixelphone/thread/132146709/in-android-12-can-you-manually-change-text-color-without-using-themes-or-changing-wallpaper?hl=en

Comment: @londonBadger Checks the answer ;)

Comment: Btw how did you managed to run live wp using libGDX. Have been trying since weeks but failing

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes across this post because they're facing the same issue, I was able to fix this by using the #FFFFFF tag in the styles.xml file.

Hope this helps!